# Multiple SQL request on cx_Oracle?

Tags: cx-oracle

I use cx_Oracle a Python Interface for Oracle Database.

In the same query, I have to:

1. Change session to CDB container
2. do a SQL request

Here is my code:

```
Query = f"""ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=cdb$root;
                    select RESOURCE_NAME as "Parametre", 
                           MAX_UTILIZATION as "Valeur courrante", 
                           LIMIT_VALUE as "Valeur limite",
                           decode( nvl( MAX_UTILIZATION, 0),0, 0,  ceil ( ( MAX_UTILIZATION / LIMIT_VALUE) * 100) ) as "Pourcentage utilise"
                from v$resource_limit 
                where RESOURCE_NAME in ('sessions','processes')
                  and decode( nvl( MAX_UTILIZATION, 0),0, 0,  ceil ( ( MAX_UTILIZATION / LIMIT_VALUE) * 100) ) > {seuil_max_occupation_param}"""
            SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(Query,conn)
```

But this code occurs an Oracle errors:

```
ORA-00922: option erronee ou absente
```

This set of request wors fine on SQLPlus for example.
I have a syntax problem but which one?
Thans a lot.
Best regards.
théo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Oracle APIs execute a single *statement* at a time. From the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html):

> cx_Oracle can be used to execute individual statements, one at a time. It does not read SQL*Plus “.sql” files.

You need to make multiple calls to `execute()`, passing the ALTER first, and then the SELECT. You need to use the same connection for both calls.
Alternatively you could wrap the SQL calls in a PL/SQL block (and return a [REF CURSOR](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ref_cursor.py) or [Implicit Result Set](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/implicit_results.py)).

Comment: Thanks. Please condider this code: dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(....)
            conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='system', password=xxxxxx, dsn=dsn_tns) 
                
            Query = """ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=cdb$root"""
            SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(Query,conn) On Oracle 12c DB with CDB / PDBs, I get an error " 'NoneType' object is not iterable" or ORA-24964 and I don't undestand why?

Comment: Do some googling and debugging.  If you still have a problem, open a new question.  Don't forget that an `ALTER SESSION` command does not return rows.